Imported SoilGrid layer only returns black on Google Earth Engine
I'm running this code to export a layer to google earth later. When I Import it it only return black as per the image, here's my code for reference :
 
var geometry = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[
 [56.519221253820746,23.233315589710905],
 [56.5387906507934,23.233315589710905],
 [56.5387906507934,23.248142390772678],
 [56.519221253820746,23.248142390772678],
 [56.519221253820746,23.233315589710905]]], null, false);


var regionName = "myRegion"; 
var variableName = "bdod"; 
var image = ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/" + variableName + "_mean");

var crs = "EPSG:4326"; 
var resolution = 150; 
var singleBand = false;


Map.centerObject(geometry);
var noDataVal = -32768;
image = image.mask(image.neq(0)).unmask(noDataVal);

function exportImage(image, bandName) {
  var fileName = "soilgrids-isric_" + regionName + "_" + variableName;

  if (bandName) {
    fileName = "soilgrids-isric_" + regionName + "_" + bandName;
  }

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: fileName,
    folder: 'soilgrids',
    fileNamePrefix: fileName,
    region: geometry,
    scale: resolution,
    crs: crs,
    formatOptions: {
      cloudOptimized: true,
      noData: noDataVal
    }
  });
}

if (singleBand) {
  // Export each band separately
  var bandList = image.bandNames();
  bandList.evaluate(function(bands) {
    bands.forEach(function(band) {
      var singleBandImage = image.select([band]);
      exportImage(singleBandImage, band);
    });
  });
} else {
  exportImage(image, null);
}



I am having exactly the same issue when downloading the rasters directly from https://soilgrids.org/. Has anyone managed to download raster layers from SoilGrids recently ?
Thanks
